org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to execute tests
I am having one java project in which added groovy test cases and I uses below:
maven dependency.
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.spockframework/spock-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4-M4-groovy-3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.21</version>
        </dependency>

When I am trying to run these test cases using Intellij then getting below error:
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to execute tests

    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:153)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/store/NamespacedHierarchicalStore$CloseAction
    at org.spockframework.runtime.StoreProvider.<clinit>(StoreProvider.java:29)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpockExecutionContext.<init>(SpockExecutionContext.java:50)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpockEngine.createExecutionContext(SpockEngine.java:36)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpockEngine.createExecutionContext(SpockEngine.java:12)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.support.store.NamespacedHierarchicalStore$CloseAction
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 21 more

I tried different versions of groovy but same error

<version>2.4-M4-groovy-4.0</version> is for groovy 4, and then you load groovy 3

Have tried  2.4-M4-groovy-3.0 also for Spock but same error

You've added the junit engine too, yeah? <dependency>             <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>             <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>             <version>5.5.2</version>             <scope>test</scope>         </dependency>

There may be a more recent version... That's an example

<version>5.10.2</version> is latest stable I think

@tim_yates is correct, Spock 2.4 requires JUnit 5.10.2 or newer

But why should he add the Jupiter engine when he wants to use Spock? The Jupiter engine is for writing Jupiter tests. spock-core itself is the engine he should need. But maybe he declared some older version of junit-platform-engine and Maven with its strange "nearest-wins" strategy would then use that old version instead of the one Spock needs.

The official sample project could be a good starting point:
https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/blob/master/pom.xml
